Artin-Schreier extension is cyclic of degree 1 or $p$

Let $K$ be a ﬁeld of characteristic $p > 0$ and $K \subset L$ the extension obtained by adjoining the zeros of the Artin–Schreier polynomial $f = x^p − x − a \in K[x]$, where $a\in K^*$, to $K$. Show that $K \subset L$ is a cyclic extension of degree either 1 or $p$.

My attempt:
First I showed that $f$ is in fact irreducible in $K[x]$ of degree $p$. In fact, if $\alpha\in\overline{K}$ is a root of $f$, then $\alpha+k$, for all $k=0,...,p-1$, are all the roots of $f$. That would prove that $L$ is cyclic, I think, since then
$L=K[\alpha]$.
But I can't seem to show that $L$ has degree 1 or $p$. I would think that it's obvious that $L$ has degree $p$, since the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ is $f$ which has degree $p$, if I'm not doing something wrong. But I have no idea how to show that $L$ could have degree 1.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

I got the same problem for my homework next Monday. This polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p$ if $a\in\mathbb{F}^_p$. Note that $\mathbb{F}^_p\subset K^$. So for any a in $\mathbb{F}^_p$ this polynomial can be reducible in $K[X]$. Which means you have two cases.: If a root is in K than it has all of them which means that K=L and it has degree 1 or the second case if it has one root in L. Then all of the other roots lie in L and are the conjugates as you described them.

Yo Alex ben jij dit? whahaha

No but that's really funny. Thanks!!

Volg je algebra 3 Leiden?

It is not true that $f$ is irreducible if $a$ equals $\alpha^p - \alpha$ for some $\alpha \in K$, as then $f(X) = (X-\alpha)(X-\alpha-1)\cdots(X-\alpha-(p-1))$ and $L = K$ is of degree $1$.
So assume $a$ is not of this form, and let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^p - x - a$ in $\bar K$.
Then, as you noticed, $L = K[\alpha]$ (as all other roots are of the form $\alpha + k$ with $k \in \mathbb{F}_p$) so $L|K$ is at most of degree $p$ ($\alpha$ is cancelled by a polynomial of degree $p$).
An element $n \in \mathbb{F}_p$ acts on $L$ by mapping $\alpha$ to $\alpha+n$, which shows that $L$ has at least $p$ automorphisms; since it is at most of degree $p$, it is actually Galois of degree exactly $p$ with exactly $p$ automorphisms and its Galois group is $\mathbb{F}_p \simeq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.
(By the way, all cyclic extensions of degree $p$ of $K$ are obtained in this way, and two elements $a, a' \in K$ induce the same extension if and only if they differ by an element of the form $\alpha^p - \alpha$ for some $\alpha \in K$, but these facts are nontrivial)
